# .NET 6 ASP.NET MVC project running on a IIS Server without .NET 6 installed. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-5, .net-6.0

I have a big application made in ASP.NET MVC using .NET 5.

We wanted to test the feasibility and the possibility to bring it to .NET 6.
Usually, but not always these kind of operations are mostly painless because you just need to upgrade project framework to from .NET 5 to .NET6 (and vs2019 to vs2022)

Why I can run a web application built with .NET 6 in a server with .NET 5 installed?

Now, I did that upgrade, and to test it, I deployed our application to a test IIS server we have where the application is already up and running, with these installed, which are all part of Microsoft .NET 5.0.6 Hosting Bundle:

-Microsoft .NET 5.0.6 - Windows Server Hosting
-Microsoft .NET Runtime 5.0.6 both x86 and 64
-Visual C++ Redistributables

I then deployed the application with dotnet build command in release mode and deployed on it and to my surprise.... IT WORKED

I was quite sure I had to install .NET 6 hosting bundle or something, but I didn't.

Why?
I remember on the other .NET Framework projects, that if you made a project for a certain version of .NET Framework, but in your code you only used functionalities of the old ones, the project build would run without the need to install the new .NET Framework version.
Example:

I create a Console application which has targetframework "C# 9.0 released with .NET 5.0"

but in the code I don't use any of the new constructs and syntax in c# 9.0 but all the code uses C#8.0 constructs, I could run it on a machine with  .NET Core 3.0 because it doesn't use any of the new constructs.

This is what is happening?
It means that I have an application with .NET 6 framework but in reality the server is not upgraded and is running with .NET 5 just because in the code I didn't use any of the C#10 new constructs and syntax?

Thanks

Comment: VS you can target the app to work with any version of Net. If build has Net 4.8 installed you can target Net 5 or Net 6. Deploy machine would need the runtime version of either Net 6 or Net 5 installed. Core is a little different. Core was developed so Net would run on a Linux operating system.  So what Microsoft has been slowly doing is modifying Windows Operating System so same functions will work on both Linux and Windows.  It was a lot of work to modify the Windows code so it has been done in stages.  So best way is to build on machine with latest Net version and then target other version.

Comment: @jdweng I didn't really understood how all the linux-windows thing fits in this. But I remember that in old .NET (up to 4.8) if you wanted to run an application you needed the relative .net framework installed, if you wanted to use the latest language features. Compiler would block you otherwise.

Here I have a web application on which I changed .NET 5 TargetFramework in .NET 6, which is running fine on a IIS Server with a .NET 5.0.6 Runtime install.
How this is possible? Shouldn't it require .NET 6 installed on the server?

Comment: It depends on features you are using not are features were changed between Net 5 and 6.  So if you are compiling in Net 6 and only using the methods that didn't change between 5 & 6 the code will run.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, that's what I tought it was happening.
So basically to fully upgrade everything I would need to install .NET 6 on server, even if my application doesn't make use of .NET 6 features.
Would you recommend it as a future code upgrade since .NET 6 has entered LTS stage?
My application does not use .NET 6 or C#10 syntax, but overall, .NET 6 would mean keeping up with the last updates.

Comment: AS I said you build with Net Framework latest version and target version being used.  You install the runtime version of the deploy machine.  See : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download?force_isolation=true